# NSPredicate for SQL 'Like'

Tags: ios, nspredicate, azure-mobile-services, sql-like

I am trying to query in Azure Mobile Services from iOS.

How can I create NSPredicate for SQL of  WHERE City LIKE '%term%'   ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's [NSPredicate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)

Simple comparisons, such as grade == "7" or firstName like "Shaffiq"
Case and diacritic insensitive lookups, such as name contains[cd] "itroen"
Logical operations, such as (firstName like "Mark") OR (lastName like "Adderley")

You can create predicates for relationships, such as:
group.name like "work*"

Also see [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/) on `NSPredicate`.
LIKE: The left hand expression equals the right-hand expression: ? and * are allowed as wildcard characters, where ? matches 1 character and * matches 0 or more characters.

More:
in "[cd]" the "c" means case insensitive and the "d" means to ignore diacritical marks. Unless you have a special need always use "d". An example: In a subway app I could not lookup a subway station in Paris because there was a diacritical mark in the name and the search function did not use "d".

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"City LIKE[c] %@", city];
```

Where city is NSString instance containing city term. [c] sets case insensitivity.